Can the timeout duration of ChatClient be adjusted?
When I use ChatClient to request an LLM model, I always get a timeout error after one minute. Are there any parameters that can be modified to change the timeout, or can you tell me how to adjust it? Thank you very much!
enter image description here
enter image description here
When I use ChatClient to request an LLM model, I always get a timeout error after one minute. Are there any parameters that can be modified to change the timeout, or can you tell me how to adjust it? Thank you very much!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

From my knowledge there are no option to configure timeout , I think it is limitation from moldes and can very from model to model.
